# The changes package and british babel: Undefined control sequence

Tags: babel, changes

Using the `changes` package, whenever I use the `babel` package with the `british` option, I get an "Undefined control sequence" error that points to the line where I want to use the changes markup. However, I do not get any errors when `british` is replaced with `english`. Minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}

Some old text. \added{Something new.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Same happens with Spanish babel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `changes` package supports a few `babel` languages, but not `british`.

You can solve the issue by adding the support yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{changes}

\addto\captionsbritish{\def\listofchangesname{List of changes}}
\addto\captionsbritish{\def\summaryofchangesname{Changes}}
\addto\captionsbritish{\def\changesaddname{Added}}
\addto\captionsbritish{\def\changesdeletename{Deleted}}
\addto\captionsbritish{\def\changesreplacename{Replaced}}
\addto\captionsbritish{\def\changesauthorname{Author}}
\addto\captionsbritish{\def\changesanonymousname{anonymous}}
\addto\captionsbritish{\def\changesnoloc{List of changes is available after the next \LaTeX\ run.}}
\addto\captionsbritish{\def\changesnosoc{Summary of changes is available after the next \LaTeX\ run.}}

\begin{document}

Some old text. \added{Something new.}

\end{document}
```

You can ask the package maintainer to add support, as it's really easy: I just copied the code for `english`, changing `\captionsenglish` to `\captionsbritish`.

Answer (score 0):

The *changes* package provides british translations for a while now, so no workaround is needed anymore.