# Default text for babel

Tags: babel, changes

Is there a default language definition for babel texts, so I don't have to define all possible languages?

At the moment, I define

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\def\listofchangesname{List of changes}}
```

which leads to errors when using *british* as language.

Would this be sufficient and correct LaTeX? Or is there another good solution?

```
\def\listofchangesname{List of changes}
\addto\captionsenglish{\def\listofchangesname{List of changes}}
```

This is a follow-up to [The changes package and british babel: Undefined control sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229594/the-changes-package-and-british-babel-undefined-control-sequence)

Comment: Some “fixed tags” are defined by `babel`, packages can add their own, but they should do for every language they want to support.

Comment: With the `translations` package it is possible to declare fallback translations which are used in the case of an unknown language, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193452/5049

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`tracklang`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tracklang) package, which I wrote to deal with that type of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studying the documentation I am using language texts as follows:

For language dependent texts without babel:

```latex
\def\listofchangesname{List of changes}
```

If the babel package is used without language, default is `english`, thus I define at least:

```latex
\addto\captionsenglish{\def\listofchangesname{List of changes}}
```

In the text you use `\listofchangesname` directly, if the `babel` package is not loaded, the first definition is used, if the babel package is loaded, the babel definition of the language is used.

Thus, both cases work but you have to define the default language texts twice.